# Sql instance number in new column

Tags: sql, instance, counting

I have a table with userid in one column, purchase date in second column, and purchase item in the third. I ordered the table by purchase date and want to make a fourth column to record the count instance number of the user. See below for example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUZg9.png)

Eventually I want to create a table that shows how much each user bought during the purchase. For example their first purchase they spent 10 second purchase 20 third purchase 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the window function [`row_number`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/).

```
select
  *,
  row_number() over(
    partition by userid
    order by purchasedate
  ) as instance
from that_table
```